# Iterable.isEmpty or isNotEmpty

Tags: dart

Why do Iterable classes in Dart have both the `isEmpty` and `isNotEmpty` fields? Is it purely for readability? (According to the [documentation](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-core.Iterable#id_isEmpty), it suggests so).

Would there be any circumstances where `list.isEmpty == list.isNotEmpty` is true?

Comment: I think its just for readability, code reads nicer `if( cats.isNotEmpty )` rather than `if( !cats.isEmpty )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the way they're implemented.
[According to *IterableBase/Mixin* and *Base/Mixin*:](https://github.com/dart-lang/bleeding_edge/blob/master/dart/sdk/lib/collection/list.dart#L69)

```dart
bool get isNotEmpty => !isEmpty;
```

As long as they use the Mixin, **.isEmpty == .isNotEmpty** cant be true then... i guess..?